# select input fields css ignored on moblie device

Tags: html

We have several sites that have recently started displaying select input fields differently to other fields in the form.  Previously they were all uniform, as per the first screenshot which is what we see on a mac desktop.  The Suburb field is a normal text field, the other 4 fields are select input fields.

[image: desktop screenshot contact form]

On my iPhone and iPad in either Safari, Chrome or Firefox, the select input fields are ignoring the css applicable to all fields in the form (see second screenshot).

[image: iphone screenshot contact form]

I found some posts about setting the "appearance" css property but this does not seem to have any influence on how the field is displaying.  I have used the following css rule.

```
select, option {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

initially I started with just the appearance properties and the rule was only applicable to select but other posts suggested including option and a property for border-radius.

Is anyone able to provide advice on how we get the select fields to display like the desktop version?

Thanks in advance.

Greg J

Comment: 1) Have you passed the code through both an HTML as well as a CSS validator?
2) Are you sure your CSS code is not responsive to display things different on Mobile?

Comment: I went to the W3 validator page and I did find a couple of errors. 1 error was an image was missing an alt property, the other was a style tag was inside the body tag.  I moved the css to the main css page.
THIS HAS FIXED THE ISSUE!  Thank you!